# Is there any way to stop Steam client updates?

Tags: steam

[image]

I searched a lot about this but can't find the solution. All results show that how can you disable a game update in steam. But I need to stop the Steam software updates itself.

Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @Tacoタコス it's just that whenever I start my PC and open Steam app, it will first do some updates which is irritating.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I didn't believe that was actually an answer, but I'm more than happy to write it up.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can prevent it by not restarting your computer and having steam run all the time with at least 1 game active. I usually run Idle games in the background for several weeks on end without rebooting and steam never bugs me for updates. This is by far a decent solution of course.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to prevent it from updating, since that means it will eventually stop working. Which in turn could mean that games relying on auto updates might also stop working, at least in online modes. If you insist, here's some tips in the [Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/1639788130289877816/). I haven't tried them personally and can't vouch for them.

It might make more sense block it from auto launching and starting annoying updates at computer boot-up:

- Top left corner: Steam -> Settings.
- Interface. "Uncheck Run Steam when my computer starts"

Comment: The surest way to make a program stop working is by updating it, while software that is not updated keeps working - potentially forever. Currently there is a banner in the Steam Client saying that in 36 days, the program will stop running. Not because of a problem with the software, but because of a decision. The way in which Steam will make its client stop working, is by forcing an update which stops it from running. Do you see how your assumption ("don't prevent updates, because it might stop it from working") is completely wrong, and that preventing forced updates makes software work?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson You seem to be under the impression that all computer games run offline in single player mode and not relying on servers, which in turn require a certain client version. That's how a whole lot of games work this side of the millennium.

Comment: A client version of the game, yes. That's under game updates, not Steam client updates. You have the two confused. The Steam client is most often updated to make changes to or address problems with, its UI mimicking the website. Most of these web apps in desktop clothing have problems; they're not the right fit and are double the work. E.g. Discord, Spotify, etc have web versions that are good enough that you don't need a desktop client (to do the same thing) at all. I would say it's normal to have a webshop/forum/chat/etc. as a website and not a desktop app.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson I'm well aware of the difference. There's no guarantee that game updates will work through the steam client if you don't update it. Common sense.

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus is that there isn't an *official* method of disabling updates to the client. However, there are plenty of sources that recommend lowering the bandwidth Steam has available. [Steam's website](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4166-TYSC-9690) provides details on how to accomplish this:

> If you notice connection problems during Steam downloads, or want to limit how much bandwidth steam can use, go to the Limit downloads to the following bandwidth drop-down menu in the Download tab in your Steam client's settings pane. You can find it in Steam's File > Settings menu.

However, I'm not so sure this would prevent the ***client*** from updating. I'm not sure how it impacts online gameplay, but based on the previously supplied link, there are separate settings for in-game bandwidth which implies that it *should* be unaffected:

> Most connections work well with the default rate, cl_updaterate, and cl_cmdrate settings. Most servers prevent changing your in-game rate settings.
>
> Default Settings vary between games, but the following is a safe baseline for most broadband connections:
>
> - rate 30000
> - cl_updaterate 20
> - cl_cmdrate 30

If online gameplay isn't important, you can always simply disconnect from the network prior to launching Steam; and, if Steam is launched automatically when your computer starts, you can disable that by following online tutorials for your respective operating system.

Comment: Are you really suggesting the asker lower the bandwidth, so that the forced and inevitable dialog stops him from selecting a game and starting it for a much longer period?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson, I'm really summarizing what the general consensus was for a solution 2 years ago. Things might've changed since then, and if they have, feel free to write up your own answer :)

Comment: The Internet is full of wrong answers - the way to reduce the amount is to test advice before copypasting. In this forum (and on most forums) there is no onus on a critic to provide an answer because they find problems with others' answers. Currently, Valve is planning an update to make my Library unplayable. It will take effect on Jan 1. I will post my answer when my measures have been tested.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson the answer I gave isn't wrong just because you don't like it, and I'm not sure how you can assume that I didn't test the advice prior to posting it; nor how you can assume that I simply copied and pasted the content in my answer. I've always done my due diligence, especially when helping others, and this answer is no different. At the time, it offered valid avenues for the OP, even if no one liked it (including myself).